# np.cov() matrix returns unexpected values

Tags: python, numpy, covariance-matrix

I am trying to find the covariance matrix of all possible images(flattened) with each pixel - {0,1}.

I have written following code using numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array(np.meshgrid([1,0], [1, 0], [1, 0],[1,0],[0,1])).T.reshape(-1,5)
a = np.transpose(a)

covariance = np.cov(a)
print(covariance)
```

I get output `0.25806452` in the diagonal. But I think the diagonal should be exactly `0.25`.

Can anyone explain why it isn't `0.25`?

Comment: Try `np.cov(a,ddof=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being normalised by 1/(N-1), not 1/N. Set the `ddof` parameter to change this behaviour.